# IP and Wildcard VirtualHost Conflict

Tags: virtualhost

I'm trying to setup an Apache web server that has a couple WordPress Multisite installations. My goal is to have clients point their domain at one of the IP addresses say 209.50.xxx.xxx and that traffic gets directed to the WP Multisite directory. I also have other domains that need to go to a specific directory regardless of what their IP address is. I can't seem to get both IP Based and Wildcard VirtualHosts working together. I can only get one or the other. In the current setup below, I can get traffic on any domain pointed at 209.50.xxx.xxx to go to the correct directory, but app.example.com and www.example.com will just get an error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

```
## All Traffic to IP: 209.50.xxx.xxx on Port 80 (Catch All) ##
<VirtualHost 209.50.xxx.xxx:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example/site/public
</VirtualHost>

## All Traffic to IP 209.50.xxx.xxx on Port 80 with Domain app.example.com  ##
<VirtualHost 209.50.xxx.xxx:80>
        ServerName app.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example/app/public
</VirtualHost>

## All Traffic to any IP on Port 80 with Domain www.example.com or example.com ##
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example/main/public
</VirtualHost>

## All Traffic to any IP on Port 80 with Domain www.other-example.com or other-example.com ##
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.other-example.com
        ServerAlias other-example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/other-example/main/public
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried different ordering with the current virtualhost catchall at the beginning flipped to the end with the same results.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Any reason why you are mixing NameBased and IPBased VirtualHosting?

Comment: Some of the sites have set domains (which is normal), and other sites like the WordPress multisite setups, I'm hoping to have all traffic from a specific IP directed at it so that clients can simply point their domain at that IP and it goes to the correct WP installation.

Answer (score 0):

I setup a virtualbox with 2 IP addresses so that I could carefully test different virtual host configurations, and I believe that I have the solution. It seems that if I start using IP addresses in the VirtualHost line (`<VirtualHost 192.168.1.201:80>` instead of `<VirtualHost *:80>`) then I need to do that for every VirtualHost block. Then for the "Catch-All" blocks for each IP, I keep that first at the top of the file (The order is important.)